# How to get the date period by months in pgSQL as an integer

Tags: php, postgresql, date, stored-procedures

How can I get the date period by months in pgsql. I need to divide a value by month range of the date period. Like **2016/01/31** and **2016/03/31** have **2 months** of period and I need to divide a value **by 2**. I am sending two dates as parameters for the pgSQL stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Function Date Period by Months Period Return Integer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_period(start_date varchar,end_date varchar) RETURNS integer AS $LABEL$
DECLARE 
v_result integer;
BEGIN

select into v_result date_part('months',end_date::date)- date_part('months',start_date::date) as date_period;

/* v_result is integer */
RETURN (v_result);

/* COMMENTS THIS IF YOU IN DEBUG MODE */
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN (999);

END;
$LABEL$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

## EXEC: SELECT * FROM date_period('2016/01/31','2016/05/31');

FOR DIFFERENT YEAR YOU COULD USE THIS FUNCTION

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_period(start_date varchar,end_date varchar) RETURNS integer AS $LABEL$
DECLARE 
v_result integer;
BEGIN

select into v_result ((extract( epoch from end_date::date)-extract( epoch from start_date::date))/60/60/24/30)::integer as date_period;

/* v_result is integer */
RETURN (v_result);

/* COMMENTS THIS IF YOU IN DEBUG MODE */
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN (999);

END;
$LABEL$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

**EXEC: SELECT * FROM date_period('2016/01/31','2017/03/31');**

Comment: How do I use that variable? When I write
`sum(column_name)/variable` , it gives me an error "column "period" does not exist"

Comment: Hi. Have a little issue. If my dates are '2016/01/31' and '2017/03/31'. It shows 2 months instead of 14 months. Could you please help me with that.

Comment: @CuriousCoder i already edit my answer. glad if you upvote it. thanks :)

Comment: @AdrianHartanto Thank you, your answer is helping me. @ CuriousCoder You should Mark As Answer if it's helping you.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHartanto. I dont have enough reputation for upvoting :(